# loop a function with multiple arguments

Tags: bash, loops, arguments, slice

I have a bash script where I call the same function seven times with three arguments, but arguments are different each time:

```
snmpset_f 16 i 6
snmpset_f 16 i 5
snmpset_f 15 s "ping_test"
snmpset_f 2 i 1
snmpset_f 3 d "192 168 1 2"
snmpset_f 4 i 1
snmpset_f 5 i 64
```

I find it bit ugly and clunky. If `snmpset_f` function had just one argument, I would simply do `for arg in 16 16 15 2 3 4 5; do snmpset_f "$arg"; done`. However, it has three. `for arg in "16 i 6" "16 i 5" ...` does not work either because then the all three arguments are passed to function as one. Is there a way to optimize this script and loop a function with multiple arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it wasn't for `"192 168 1 2"`, you could rely on the shell's word-splitting with

```
for arg in "16 i 6" "16 i 5"; do
    snmpset_f $arg
done
```

`bash` arrays are also not quite first-class objects, or you could do something like

```
for arg in (16 i 6) (3 d "192 168 1 2"); do
```

However, if it is only the *3rd* argument that might contain whitespace, you can try reading from a here document:

```
while read -r arg1 arg2 arg3; do
    snmpset_f "$arg1" "$arg2" "$arg3"
done <<EOF
16 i 6
16 i 5
15 s ping_test
2 i 1
3 d 192 168 1 2
4 i 1
5 i 64
EOF
```

Note that no quotes are necessary for the IP-address-looking argument, since `read` only splits the line on the first two instances of whitespace; everything else goes as-is into the third argument.

Answer (score 1):

### Loop Over Positional Parameters in Chunks

You didn't show your actual function code, so you'll have to adapt as necessary. You can use [positional parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters), [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), and the shift command to address this problem by chunking your arguments to a function.

#### Example Code

Basically, the trick is to use the length of *snmpset_f_args* to pass arguments in chunks to your function until you run out of top-level positional parameters. For example:

```
snmpset_f () {
    # Loop over the parameters passed to this function.
    for arg in "$@"; do
        echo -n "$arg "
    done
    echo
}

# Explicitly set your positional parameters if necessary.
set -- 16 16 15 2 3 4 5

# Define how many arguments at a time to process.
snmpset_f_args=3

# Call the function until we run out of parameters.
while [[ $# -ne 0 ]]; do
    snmpset_f "${@:1:$snmpset_f_args}"
    # You have to shift one at a time in a loop, because shift won't
    # shift if invoked with more parameters than you have.
    for arg in $(seq 1 $snmpset_f_args); do
        shift
    done
done
```

#### Sample Results

Given the data set in your post, the code above will print the following to standard output:

```
16 16 15 
2 3 4 
5
```